# On ARM macOS when explicitly raise()-ing a signal, some return addresses are garbled on the stack

Tags: c, macos, arm, arm64, stack-unwinding

Here's a simple program for ARM macOS that installs a signal handler for `SIGSEGV`, then generates one. In the signal handler function, the stack is walked with the usual frame pointer chasing algorithm, then the symbolized version is printed out:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void handler(int signum, siginfo_t* siginfo, void* context)
{
    __darwin_ucontext* ucontext = (__darwin_ucontext*) context;
    __darwin_mcontext64* machineContext = ucontext->uc_mcontext;
    
    uint64_t programCounter = machineContext->__ss.__pc;
    uint64_t framePointer = machineContext->__ss.__fp;
    
    void* bt[100];
    int n = 0;
    while (framePointer != 0) {
        bt[n] = (void*)programCounter;
        
        programCounter = *(uint64_t*)(framePointer + 8);
        framePointer = *(uint64_t*)(framePointer);
        
        ++n;
    }

    char** symbols = backtrace_symbols(bt, n);
    printf ("Call stack:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf ("\t %s\n", symbols[i]);
    }

    free (symbols);
    
    abort ();
}

void Crash ()
{
    raise (SIGSEGV);
    //*(volatile int*)0 = 0;
}

int main()
{
    struct sigaction sigAction;
    sigAction.sa_sigaction = handler;
    sigAction.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigaction (SIGSEGV, &sigAction, nullptr);
    
    Crash ();
}
```

This works fine when a "regular" `SIGSEGV` happens, but when it's raised explicitly, return values on the stack seem garbled, specifically, the upper part seems to contain garbage:

```
Call stack:
     0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x0000000185510e68 __pthread_kill + 8
     1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x116a000185422e14 raise + [...] // Should be 0x0000000185422e14
     2   SignalHandlerTest                   0x8f6a000104bc3eb8 _Z5Crashv + [...] // Should be 0x0000000104bc3eb8
     3   SignalHandlerTest                   0x0000000104bc3ef8 main + 56
     4   libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000185561450 start + 4
```

The behavior is the same regardless of which signal is raised. What am I missing?

Comment: Could this be an effect of pointer authentication (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/preparing_your_app_to_work_with_pointer_authentication)?

Comment: They aren't garbled... the upper 16bits are being used for something... I'd venture @Codo has the right of it.

Comment: Maybe not the issue here, but you are sure that all the functions in your program are actually compiled to use frame pointers?  I'm not sure whether it's the default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Codo has correctly identified, this is [PAC](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/preparing_your_app_to_work_with_pointer_authentication).
The upper bits of the address are not garbled, but rather contain a salted hash of the register's lower bits.

And contrary to your claims, this happens with regular segfaults too. For example, calling `fprintf(NULL, "a");` results in:

```
Call stack:
     0   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x000000019139d8a0 flockfile + 28
     1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x1d550001913a5870 vfprintf_l + 2113595600120315944
     2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x341c80019139efd0 fprintf + 3755016926808506440
     3   t                                   0x5f29000100483e9c Crash + 6857011907648290844
     4   t                                   0x0000000100483edc main + 56
     5   libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001914b1430 start + 4
```

This is because all system binaries, including libraries, are compiled for the arm64e ABI and will make use of PAC. Now, your binary is running as a regular old arm64 binary and would crash if it passed an unsigned function pointer to a library function, or got a signed one returned. So the kernel actually disables 3 of the 4 keys that your process can use (IA, IB, DA and DB). But one of those, IB, is used solely for stack frames and so that one is left enabled even in arm64 binaries.

The reason why some return addresses are still not signed though is:

- The `main + 56` and `start + 4` were pushed by your code, which is arm64 and hence doesn't sign them.
- The `flockfile + 28` is the instruction that crashed, whose address was never pushed to the stack, but extracted from the thread state.

So everything's working exactly as it's supposed to.

---

#### Edit:

After attempting to use this to aid me in debugging myself, I find the PAC'ed addresses to be annoying after all. You commented about `ptrauth_strip` in `ptrauth.h`, but that will actually not work inside an arm64 process (it's aliased to a macro that does nothing), nor will `__builtin_ptrauth_strip` (the compiler will error out).
The compiler won't even let you use a raw `xpaci` instruction when targeting arm64, but nothing on the hardware level prevents the instruction from working, so you can still manually inject the opcode.

Based on this, I wrote a signal handler that properly strips PAC signatures from an arm64 process:

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <execinfo.h>

#ifdef __arm64__

extern void* xpaci(uint64_t pc);
__asm__
(
    "_xpaci:\n"
    "    mov x1, x30\n"
    "    mov x30, x0\n"
    "    .4byte 0xd50320ff\n" // xpaclri
    "    mov x0, x30\n"
    "    ret x1\n"
);

#else

static inline void* xpaci(uint64_t pc)
{
    return (void*)pc;
}

#endif

static void handler(int signum, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *ctx)
{
    _STRUCT_MCONTEXT64 *mctx = ((_STRUCT_UCONTEXT*)ctx)->uc_mcontext;
#ifdef __arm64__
    uint64_t orig_pc = mctx->__ss.__pc;
    uint64_t orig_fp = mctx->__ss.__fp;
#elif defined(__x86_64__)
    uint64_t orig_pc = mctx->__ss.__rip;
    uint64_t orig_fp = mctx->__ss.__rbp;
#else
#   error "Unknown arch"
#endif

    uint64_t pc = orig_pc;
    uint64_t fp = orig_fp;
    size_t n = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        if(!xpaci(pc))
        {
            break;
        }
        ++n;
        if(!fp)
        {
            break;
        }
        pc = ((uint64_t*)fp)[1];
        fp = ((uint64_t*)fp)[0];
    }
    void **bt = malloc(n * sizeof(void*));
    if(!bt)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(-1);
    }
    pc = orig_pc;
    fp = orig_fp;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        bt[i] = xpaci(pc);
        if(!fp)
        {
            break;
        }
        pc = ((uint64_t*)fp)[1];
        fp = ((uint64_t*)fp)[0];
    }
    char **sym = backtrace_symbols(bt, n);
    fprintf(stderr, "Caught signal with call stack:\n");
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", sym[i]);
    }
    free(sym);
    free(bt);
    exit(-1);
}
```

It uses `xpaclri` rather than `xpaci`, since the former is a NOP on arm64 (non-arm64e) hardware while the latter would be undefined.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thank you! Is there an official API to convert these signed pointers to regular ones? Like [DecodePointer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb432242(v=vs.85)) for Windows. Of course, I could simply clear the high bits, but it'd be better not to rely on implementation details directly.

Comment: Ah, it's right in the documentation that you've linked in your post (`ptrauth_strip` macro from `ptrauth.h`)...

Comment: @Donpedro `ptrauth_strip` won't actually work from an arm64 process... but I updated my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed, even directly using the __builtin_ptrauth_strip intrinsic fails. It seems like clang is under the assumption that arm64 and arm64e code never has to interact. In my code I used `asm ("xpaci %0" : "+r" (*ptr));`, which seems to works correctly.

Comment: @Siguza: is there a way to test if CPU supports that instruction before using that asm snippet?

Comment: @c00000fd updated my code to work on arm64e, arm64 and x86_64 hardware.

Comment: @c00000fd, xpaci and xpaclri are conditioned to Arm feature FEAT_PAuth which can be read through sysctl(), system call or command line, from hw.optional.arm.FEAT_PAuth.