# How to know & log which instruction caused SIGABRT in my macOS daemon?

Tags: c++, macos, apple-m1, arm64, sigabrt

I've written a macOS launch daemon in C++ (that runs on Apple M2 chip, which I believe uses the ARM64 architecture.) I noticed in the log that once in a while my daemon causes the SIGABRT with calling pid of my own process:

> SIGNAL: SIGABRT, sig_info=0x16bbea7c0 >
> {si_signo=6, si_errno=0, si_code=0, si_pid=3320:"MyDaemon", si_uid=0, si_status=6,
> si_addr=0x18b0ab224, si_value=0x0, si_band=0}

The handler for the signal allows me to retrieve the context of the signal:

```
void signalCallback(int sig, siginfo_t *info, void *context)
{
}
```

The question is how do I retrieve the faulty operation that caused SIGABRT?

Or better yet, a callstack?

Comment: @user17732522 i think info->si_addr shows the address that it was trying to read from and not the instruction that did it.

Comment: Different question, same answer: [On ARM macOS when explicitly raise()-ing a signal, some return addresses are garbled on the stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69118115/on-arm-macos-when-explicitly-raise-ing-a-signal-some-return-addresses-are-gar)

Comment: @Siguza: why do you think it's [PAC](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/preparing_your_app_to_work_with_pointer_authentication)? The high bits are not set in `si_addr` that I showed.

Comment: I never said that. I said "different question, same answer". The answer to the linked question performs a full stack trace dump.